# Create new layer by selection within ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, buffer, model

I have a basic abutters model built so far. Right now I have it set up to:

1. Select a parcel by an expression.
2. Buffer parcel by a value.
3. Select by location which highlights all parcels within the buffered area.

I would like to have a new feature class created with only the selected parcel between steps 1 and 2. I tried putting copy features between the output of the first selection and the buffer, but a new feature class of just the selected isn't created.

I would like to do this so the selected parcel has a separate symbology than the rest of the parcels.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Want to confirm that you've tried this: select a parcel -> copy selection to new FC -> Buffer new FC -> Select by location using the buffer -> copy the selection to another new FC. You also said that the final FC doesn't get added to your data frame (this can be set), does the FC get created at all?

Comment: Its actually not being created at all I just checked the output geodatabase its only creating the buffer FC. I added the copy features at the end as you suggested, and came up with the same results.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your model?  Or a link to a copy of the image?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your model, here is what I suggest you do to make your model perform the way you are expecting it to.  Your model should be built in the following order:

1. Instead of the "Select" too, use the "[Make Feature Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000)" tool.  Not only will this allow you to use a Featureclass (from disk, not ArcMap TOC) or a Layer (from ArcMap TOC), you can also apply a "where_clause" to select certain features by expression, just like you have in your "Select" tool parameter.
2. You do not need to copy features in Step 2.  All geoprocessing tools work on the currently selected set.
3. There is no need to use buffer in Step 3 unless you actually want the buffer shape written to disk.  The  "Select by Location" tool allows you to add a parameter for buffer distance.
4. Use "Select Layer by Location", just as you have it, but exposed and apply a value to the "search_distance" parameter.
5. Finally, use the "Copy Features" tool to output the results of your "Select By Location" to a new featureclass and write the layer to disk.  Be sure to right-click and choose "Add to Display" to get the output of this function to automatically add to your ArcMap TOC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVAPt.jpg) and [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IEEm.jpg)

it outputs three FC

1. the selected point (parcel in your case)
2. the buffer around that selection
3. the features which are within the buffer

Each have been symbolized uniquely.

Comment: I tried building a new model based on this one, however it isn't creating any new FC at all! Here is a link of my model (the answer has to be right in front of my face and i just don't see it)

http://imgur.com/LWuLsmA

Comment: Is Background GP On/Off? In the Geoprocessing Options window what is checked on in the "Display/Temp Data" section? and does the tool run completely with no errors? The FC have got to be somewhere! haha

Comment: I have the add results of geoprocessing operations to display checked..and there are no errors during the process.

Comment: Is anything set as Intermediate?

Comment: everything is set to managed and add to display. Nothing is set to intermediate. I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: "When data elements are managed by the model, they are stored by default in the scratch workspace (if this environment is set) or other system paths" [(Source)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Making_intermediate_data_managed_data/002w0000005p000000/)

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have "add to display" and "managed" checked off on your output (from copy features)
It could just be treating it as [intermediate data.](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000000z000000)